# When is QEMU Page table used instead of the EPT when running a virtual machine?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtualization, qemu, kvm

I am studying the set of the access bit in the QEMU page table when running a virtual machine on KVM.

In order to know if the CPU sets the access bit to 1 on QEMU page table, I wanted to answer the questions: Is the QEMU page table accessed when a vCPU is being scheduled?

So my question is : do we use the QEMU page table beside the EPT when accessing a page in the virtual machine or not? If not, when is each of the two page tables used?

Comment: What do you mean here by "QEMU page table" ?

Comment: The page table that has its root in the CR3 when the QEMU process is scheduled

Comment: That page table is only used for the QEMU process. When the vCPU is actually running it will use the guest's own stage 1 page table, and the stage 2 page table that KVM sets up for it. (Apologies for the Arm-flavoured terminology, I don't know what x86 calls stage 1 and 2.)